# Help with simplifying a couple of regex's

Tags: c#, regex

Below I have two regex's that operate on some text:

assume key = "old" and value = "new"

```
text = Regex.Replace(text,
    "\\." + change.Key + ",",
    "." + change.Value + ","
    );
text = Regex.Replace(text,
    "\\." + change.Key + ";",
    "." + change.Value + ";"
    );
```

So, ".old," and ".old;" would change to ".new," and ".new;", respectively.

I'm sure this could be shortened to one regex. How can I do this so that the string only changes when the comma and semicolon are at the end of the variable? For example, I don't want ".oldQ" to  change to ".newQ". Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET uses $ for backreferences:

```
text = Regex.Replace(text,
    @"\." + change.Key + "([,;])",
    "." + change.Value + "$1");
```

Comment: Does the "$1" mean it matches the first position after the string, or the first 1 characters?

Comment: To be more clear would "$2" return the second position after the string, or the first 2 characters after it?

Comment: The parenthesis in the first statement marked that as a group. In the second statement, everything that was matched in the parenthesis will show up in place of $1. In this case, it will put , or ; there, whichever was present in the original string. $2 would reference the second group, but we only have one capture group.

Answer (score 0):

Out of my head:

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\.(old|new),",@"\.\1;");
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to just change the middle part, so:

```
text = Regex.Replace(text,
    "\\." + change.Key + "(,|;)^",   // mark a group using "()" for substitution...
    "." + change.Value + "\1"       // use the group ("\1")
    );
```

Comment: Another form: `Regex.Replace(text, "\\." + change.Key + "(,|;)", "." + change.Value + "$1"); // note the "$"`

Comment: @jfs: Looks better... can you tell me what is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

I like using \b, like this:

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\." + change.Key + @"\b", "." + change.Value);
```

It would match on keywords followed by other delimiters, not just "," and ";", but it may still work in your case.